# Dynamically insert google DFP ad into tableview section header, with different sizes

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, google-dfp

The problem is that I don't know what size the DFP ad will be before I load the tableview cell. I am using DFP's delegate method GADAdSizeDelegate method : bannerView willChangeAdSizeTo. The method gets called when the cell is about to be on screen. (It also gets called multiple times and I don't know why.)

I am using storyboards and auto layout, the height for the section headers have to be set automatically, so I can't set heights in the tableview heightForCell delegate method.

Is this even possible?